# How to make WordPress use non-greedy shortcode parsing?

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode

I made a plugin that adds a shortcode with optional content. If there's no content, WordPress still tries looking for a closing tag. This is clearer with an example:

```
[span class="foo"]
[span class="bar"]
[span class="baz"]stuff[/span]
```

Wanted:

```
<span class="foo"></span>
<span class="bar"></span>
<span class="baz">stuff</span>
```

Actual:

```
<span class="foo">
  [span class="bar"]
  [span class="baz"]stuff
</span>
```

Is there a way to make WordPress produce the first output? I'm expecting many of the plugin's users to be confused by this behavior. One way is to modify `the_content` before `do_shortcode` runs, but it's pretty hacky. Is there a clean or existing way to change this behavior?

Edit: I'm not asking why this behavior occurs, I'm asking for a good way to change this behavior.

Comment: It's the same thing because that's exactly what WordPress does: `add_filter( 'the_content', 'do_shortcode', 11 );`. What I meant was I can add a new filter to pre-process my shortcode. E.g. I can make shortcodes self-close before `do_shortcode` runs. However, I think this is a hacky solution.

Answer (score 10):

Wordpress interpreted your shortcode like this:

[image: Wordpress thought your shortcode like]

The main issue being, that you have a unclosed shortcode of the same tag in front of an enclosing shortcode of the same tag, which won't be parsed correctly. The documentation states that you might run into problems with [unclosed shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Unclosed_Shortcodes).

When you call your shortcode like this:

```
[span class="foo" /]
[span class="bar" /]
[span class="baz"]stuff[/span]
```

You will get your expected result.

Because the [self-closing marker](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Self-Closing) `/` is needed in your use-case, although it generally is considered optional, but as it forces the parser to ignore following closing tags it gets you your expected result.

The above solution is the correct usage of shortcodes according to the [WordPress Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). If you want to to pre-process your shortcode in one way or another you can do that, but generally just make your users use the correct syntax in the first place.

Comment: +1 the problem is improper use of shortcodes, not the way wordpress handles them

Comment: +1 for the excellent graphic (a picture is worth 1KB of words)

Comment: I'm writing a plugin and I'm expecting this to cause a lot of support requests. This is why I want to change this behavior rather than forcing the plugin's users to add a slash. Most shortcode plugins use either self-closing or enclosing shortcodes, not both. Since mine uses both, I'm expecting it to cause confusion.

Comment: @MarkKaplun this is proper use of shortcodes: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode

Comment: @LeoJiang,I always wonder why people ask experts and then argue with them. you are free to do whatever you want, but non closed short code is like non closed html, the browser might make it work, but it might not.

Comment: @MarkKaplun Are you telling me you use self-closing HTML tags and claim to be an expert? No one said WordPress isn't handling it correctly, I want to change it to be more intuitive for my users.

Comment: if you want to change it then it will not be wordpress shortcodes but your shortodes.If a shortcode needs to handle content it is kinda ovcious it needs to be self closing, but why whoul I want to use a shortcode that needs content to work without a content.

Answer (score 0):

A shortcode has nothing to do with opening and closing  tags! A shortcode is a way to execute a function and output the results into content.

add_shortcode('hello', myFunction);
function myFunction (){return 'Hello world';}

Putting the shortcode [hello] in your post will output Hello World.